# UITableViewController: No member 'isEditing' can be found

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have subclassed UITableViewController and I'm using a button to switch my table into editing mode. Everything is working with Objective-C this way:

```
if (self.isEditing) {
    [sender setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
} else {
    [sender setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

But now I want to implement a Swift version:

```
if self.isEditing {
    sender.setTitle("Edit", forState: .Normal)
    self.setEditing(false, animated: true)
} else {
    sender.setTitle("Done", forState: .Normal)
    self.setEditing(true, animated: true)
}
```

I'm getting Error:

> 'MyViewController' does not have a member named 'isEditing'

Why is a member missing if the only difference is I'm using Swift instead Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, not everything except the language YOU use is identical. Also Apple uses Swift instead of Objective-C for UITableViewController and its superclass UIViewController. The property you are using has a slightly different declaration between Objective-C and Swift. Both are named `editing` but the pitfall is: only Objective-C has a getter with name `isEditing`.

The Objective-C declaration is:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isEditing) BOOL editing
```

But the Swift declaration is just:

```
var editing: Bool
```

So, you have to use `editing` instead `isEditing`.

Source: iOS Developer Library - Pre-Release: http://goo.gl/AOoFQl

*If not already selected: "select Language: Both" to see Swift AND Objective-C declarations. This is very helpful if you want to translate code from Objective-C to Swift.*

Comment: Great now it works! I saw the property 'editing' before but I thought it must be for something different.

Comment: But why is Apple using different names for Swift and Objective-C?

Comment: Do you want the view controller's editing property, or the table view's editing property? When I first saw your post I thought that mistake was not using self.tableview.isEditing, but it seems view controllers also have an editing property.

Comment: I've always found properties like `editing` with a different name for the getter to be annoying. Why is the property `editing` but the getter is `isEditing`? Naming conventions are there for a reason. I'm glad if Swift is normalizing property getter/setter names.

Comment: UITableViewController inherits 'editing' from UIViewController. So, it shouldn't bother.